# Angular directive to invoke function on Main scope

Tags: angularjs

I am new to using Angular and I am running into a problem trying to bind a function call to an isolated scope. My directive looks similar to this

```
angular.module("myApp",[])  
  .directive("myDirective", function () {
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      scope: {
        scopefunc: "&"
      },
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
         var myvar=5;
         scope.handleButton = function(){
            scope.scopefunc(myvar);
         }
      }
    };
  }).controller("myController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.scopefunc = function(ID){
         alert(ID);
      };
});
```

The code works to a point. If the scope.handleButton action occurs it properly invokes the $scope.scopefunc on the main controller scope BUT the parameter myvar is not passed to the main scope - it comes across as undefined. Can someone tell me how to pass this param back to the main scope?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle? Looks fine to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div  ng-controller="myController">
    <div  my-directive scopefunc="scopefunc(id)"></div>
  </div>
</div>

angular.module("myApp",[])  
  .directive("myDirective", function () {
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      scope: {
        scopefunc: "&scopefunc"
      },
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
         var myvar=5;
         scope.scopefunc({ id: myvar });
      }
    };
  }).controller("myController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.scopefunc = function(ID){
         alert(ID);
      };
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nuf1q91L/1/)**

Comment: Perfect - thanks so much. Everything I could find to read just invoked the function.