# Getting back 'file: undefined' in dropzone.js success callback

Tags: angularjs, dropzone.js, angular-directive

I made a Angular.js directive to add a dropzone to my app and bind a function to dropzone.js success event, but I can only get the response back, and file is undefined. The response is coming from the API that uploads the file to the server. How come the file is undefined?

I can access the file when I bind to dropzone.js addedfile event, but then it messes up the dropzone flow, not showing the thumbnail.

My Angular directive:

```
angular
    .module('frontend')
    .directive('dropZone', dropZoneDirective);

function dropZoneDirective(APPSETTINGS) {
    return {
        scope: {
            successCallback: '&?'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.dropzone({
                url: APPSETTINGS.apiUrl + 'api/core/media',
                headers: {'x-wsse': API.getToken()},
                paramName: 'file',
                success: function(file, response) {
                    if (scope.successCallback != null) {
                        scope.successCallback({response: response, file: file});
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

In my HTML view:

```
<div success-callback="vm.dropzoneUploaded()" class="dropzone" drop-zone></div>
```

And the callback function in the controller:

```
vm.dropzoneUploaded = function(response, file) {
    var filename = file.filename;
    var filepath = response.path;
    var object = {
        filename: filename,
        filepath: filepath
    };
    var updated = DataFct.add(object);
}
```

Am I overlooking something basic here?

Comment: There is something wrong with how I try to send the file back on this line: `scope.successCallback({response: response, file: file})` or how I define the callback function `vm.dropzoneUploaded = function(response, file) {}` but I cannot figure out what.

Comment: This seems related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25296551/angular-directive-to-invoke-function-on-main-scope

But the answer to put the value to return in an object I am already applying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague found the answer:

In the directive I shouldn't have wrapped the return variables in an object:
`scope.successCallback(response, file);`

Now it is working and I am getting both back in my controller.